# Find different digits PHP

Tags: php

I have string

> $a = '123456789';

what it the formula so it can give result that in string there are 9 different digits.

If i have

> $a = '111222333444';

so result should be

> 4

Comment: Forget PHP. Can you explain how you'd get the answer using a pen and paper? If you can do that, then the PHP / Python / C++ / Go should come easily to you.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... can you be a little more clear?

Comment: @TerryHarvey How many unique characters in a given string?

Comment: @mcalex Ah, silly me — haven't slept. Thanks!

Comment: are all the downvotes because of no effort?  Coz it seems a reasonable question to me

Comment: @mcalex Yes, as the downvote triangles popup says "This question does not show any research effort;"

Comment: yeah, but it also refers to it being unclear or not useful which i don't agree with.  Just seems to me that copping a -6 when only one of three pillars has been missed is a tad harsh.  meh

Comment: @mcalex the problem is that question as is presented seems a homework's question, which can be fine, but nobody learns without some effort by his own.

Answer (score 6):

Wrote a quick function for you:

```
function unique_chars($string) {
    return strlen(count_chars($string, 3));
}
```

**Usage:**

```
echo unique_chars('111222333444');
```

Comment: best answer! Great use of count_chars()

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = '123456789';
$parts = str_split( $str );
$unique = array_unique( $parts );
$uniqueCount = count( $unique );
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question until you posted this. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$myString = '1111222334';
$uniqueDigits = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    if (FALSE !== strpos($myString, strval($i)))
        $uniqueDigits++;
```

The value of `$uniqueDigits` is `4`.

Comment: I am the only one in upvote this one? leaving the beauty apart, this is the most efficient solution...

Comment: It would even better a `continue` right after find a `FALSE` and replace `strval()` by `"$i"` making it more fast in case of very long strings to parse. 8)

Comment: @NomikOS the "$i" looks nicer but are you sure using `continue` would make it any faster?

Comment: lol, you right man, lol. ok, time to sleep... :D